# No network device available

Tags: wireless, ethernet

OUTPUT - sudo lshw -C network

```
*-network               


description: Network controller

product: BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN

vendor: Broadcom Corporation

physical id: 0

bus info: pci@0000:0b:00.0

version: 01

width: 32 bits

clock: 33MHz

capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list

configuration: driver=wl latency=0

resources: irq:16 memory:efcfc000-efcfffff


*-network UNCLAIMED


description: Ethernet controller

product: BCM4401-B0 100Base-TX

vendor: Broadcom Corporation

physical id: 0

bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0

version: 02

width: 32 bits

clock: 33MHz

capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list

configuration: latency=64

resources: memory:ef9fe000-ef9fffff
```

OUTPUT - ifconfig -a

```
lo        
Link encap:Local Loopback  

inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0

inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host

UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1

RX packets:259 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0

TX packets:259 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0

collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:33926 (33.9 KB)  
TX bytes:33926 (33.9 KB)
```

Content of path - etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules

```
# PCI device 0x14e4:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1e.0/0000:03:00.0/ssb1:0 (b44)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:19:b9:5a:f6:eb", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
```

OUTPUT - sudo ifconfig eth0

```
    eth0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device
```

OUTPUT - sudo ifup eth0

```
    Ignoring unknown interface eth0=eth0.
```

Answer (score 1):

Please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Hook up the ethernet temporarily and do:

```
sudo modprobe b44
```

Now your ethernet should be working and able to connect. Then do:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```

Everything should be working correctly after a reboot.